# getting extra [] at the end of json array

Tags: php, json

I am getting an extra [] at the end of the json and it is causing me problems. I tried to search why or where these [] are added but couldn't find anything.

so what I need is [{content},{content},{content}] but I am getting [{content},{content},{content}][]

The result should be:

> [{"botserialnumber":1,"name":"","phone":null,"bloodpressure":20,"isbreathing":null,"isawake":null,"heartrate":101,"readPhone":null,"readBot":1},{"botserialnumber":4,"name":"ar","phone":"7084","bloodpressure":90,"isbreathing":0,"isawake":0,"heartrate":90,"readPhone":1,"readBot":1},{"botserialnumber":6,"name":"","phone":null,"bloodpressure":1,"isbreathing":null,"isawake":null,"heartrate":5,"readPhone":null,"readBot":1}]

but instead is:

> [{"botserialnumber":1,"name":"","phone":null,"bloodpressure":20,"isbreathing":null,"isawake":null,"heartrate":101,"readPhone":null,"readBot":1},{"botserialnumber":4,"name":"ar","phone":"7084","bloodpressure":90,"isbreathing":0,"isawake":0,"heartrate":90,"readPhone":1,"readBot":1},{"botserialnumber":6,"name":"","phone":null,"bloodpressure":1,"isbreathing":null,"isawake":null,"heartrate":5,"readPhone":null,"readBot":1}]**[]**

The code used:

```
case 'getdata':

 $heroes = array();

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT botserialnumber, name, phone, bloodpressure, isbreathing, isawake, heartrate, readPhone, readBot FROM healers");


 $stmt->execute();



 $stmt->bind_result($botserialnumber, $namen, $phone, $bloodpressure, $isbreathing, $isawake, $heartrate, $readPhone,$readBot);


while($stmt->fetch()){

 //pushing fetched data in an array 
 $temp = [
  'botserialnumber'=>$botserialnumber,
   'name'=>$namen, 
   'phone'=>$phone, 
   'bloodpressure'=>$bloodpressure,
    'isbreathing'=>$isbreathing,
   'isawake'=>$isawake, 
    'heartrate'=>$heartrate,
     'readPhone'=>$readPhone,
     'readBot'=>$readBot
 ];

 //pushing the array inside the hero array 
 array_push($heroes, $temp);
}

//displaying the data in json format 
echo json_encode($heroes);



 break;
```

Comment: Code here seems ok. Something else after `break` can output `[]`.

Comment: put more code, or add exit after json_encode; Probably you have multiple json_encode() which shouldn't be like that

Comment: Try to replace the break at the end with an exit to be sure no follwing code will change your output.

Comment: `exit(0)` after the echo statement and see output

Comment: yes you guys are right thanks there was something after break doing it